# python calculate time problem in function

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, time

I'm trying to create a Parking Lot in OOP.
I got stuck in payment calculated.
The payment is only calculated in seconds, how can I make it hourly or part of it?
(Under function “VehicleLeaves” I calculated secondsDiff.seconds because if I change it to secondsDiff.hour the program will crash.)

My Code:

```
import datetime


class Cars:

    def __init__(self, phone, car_type, plate):
        self.__phone = phone
        self.__car_type = car_type
        self.__plate = plate

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Plate: {self.__plate}, Phone: {self.__phone}, Car Type: {self.__car_type}."


class ParkingLot:

    def __init__(self, name, capacity=1):
        ''' return a ParkingLot object with name "name" '''

        self.name = name
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.earnings = 0
        self.rate = 15
        self.carsAndEnterTime = {}

    def SetCapacity(self, newCap):
        ''' change the capacity from the default 1 '''
        if newCap < 1:
            raise RuntimeError("Error: parking lot size cannot be less than 1")

        self.capacity = newCap

    def GetCapacity(self):
        ''' return parking lot capacity '''
        return self.capacity

    def GetEarnings(self):
        ''' return how much much parking has made '''
        return self.earnings

    def VehicleEnters(self, vehicle):
        ''' vehicle enters parking lot'''

        # put car and its enter time in a dictionary
        self.carsAndEnterTime[vehicle] = datetime.datetime.now()

        if self.capacity == 0:
            raise RuntimeError("Error: Parking lot full!")

        self.capacity -= 1

    def VehicleLeaves(self, vehicle):
        ''' vehicle leaves parking lot. when it leaves, charges money '''

        secondsDiff = datetime.datetime.now() - self.carsAndEnterTime[vehicle]
        self.earnings += self.rate * secondsDiff.seconds
        # after earned money, delete vehicle from dictionary
        del self.carsAndEnterTime[vehicle]
        self.capacity += 1

    def __str__(self):
        ''' prints basic information of parking lot '''
        return f"Parking lot: {self.name} \nSpots open: {self.capacity} \nHourly rate:{self.rate}\n {self.carsAndEnterTime}\nEarnings: $ {self.earnings} "
```

Focus on the area in the code of time calculation:

```
   def VehicleEnters(self, vehicle):
        ''' vehicle enters parking lot'''

        # put car and its enter time in a dictionary
        self.carsAndEnterTime[vehicle] = datetime.datetime.now()

    def VehicleLeaves(self, vehicle):
        ''' vehicle leaves parking lot. when it leaves, charges money '''

        secondsDiff = datetime.datetime.now() - self.carsAndEnterTime[vehicle]
        self.earnings += self.rate * secondsDiff.seconds
        # after earned money, delete vehicle from dictionary
        del self.carsAndEnterTime[vehicle]
        self.capacity += 1
```

result in seconds, for this example is 10 seconds:

```
Earnings: $ 150
```

How can I calculate instead of seconds in hours or part of an hour rate of 15$.
For example, an hour and a half equals to 30$

what i did worng?

Comment: `secondsDiff.seconds/3600` didn't work?

Comment: If you refer to the docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) only days, seconds, and microseconds remain for a timedelta object. `<timedelta_object>.hours` is not a valid instance attribute. @rdas has the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a roundup withceil of  math module:

```
import math

secondsDiff  = datetime.datetime.now() - self.carsAndEnterTime[vehicle]
hour_roundup = math.ceil(secondsDiff.seconds/3600)
```